# How to use %%currentdate%% variable with Yoast SEO WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I am using Yoast SEO free version wordpress plugin. I am unable to use `%%currentdate%%` variable with yoast for Search Engine Title or Meta Description. Is there any way to activate this variable? Previously, I was using Rankmath, and this feature is available in Rankmath. I want use this feature with yoast.

According to my research, Yoast currentdate variable is deprecated variables.

Starting in v7.7 of Yoast, they’ve deprecated these variables as they see no valid use-case for them. They think, if these variables are used in the snippet editor, they won’t appear in the snippet preview.

I want to activate this variable to seen in snippet preview also. I have used Rankmath plugin also, and they works fine for this. Please help me to do this with Yoast.

Answer (score 1):

There are some default variable for Yoast that you can use to have current date:

- `%%currentday%%` will return the current date as a number for example : 19
- `%%currentmonth%%` will return the current month like : September
- `%%currentyear%%` will return the current year like: 2023

Answer (score 0):

I've used this method on my website, and I was going on the parameters of Yoast, and you can put the `%date` on your title and meta (post/page...)

Screen:

[image: Screen]

Comment: Please don't add links to your own website unless it's directly relevant to the question. If you add gratuitous links to your content, users may consider it spam.

Comment: ```%date%``` Variable is used to put blog post date. I want to use current date, that  update every day.